# Why is hostname verification done even though verifyHostname is false?

Tags: ssl, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

In trying to get secure rest services to work on Open Liberty in a container, I get the following error:
CWPKI0824E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  Host name verification error while connecting to host [hostname].  The host name used to access the server does not match the server certificate's SubjectDN or Subject Alternative Name information.  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: [No name matching hostname found].

Relevant portion of the server.xml:

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>appSecurity-3.0</feature>
    <feature>jca-1.7</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>mpConfig-1.3</feature>
    <feature>passwordUtilities-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<sslDefault sslRef="DefaultSSLConfig" httpHostNameVerification="false"/>

<ssl id="DefaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="DefaultKeyStore" trustStoreRef="DefaultTrustStore" trustDefaultCerts="true" verifyHostname="false"/>

<keyStore id="DefaultKeyStore" location="liberty-default-key.p12" type="PKCS12" password="password"/>
<keyStore id="DefaultTrustStore" location="liberty-default-trust.p12" type="PKCS12" password="password"/>

<ldapRegistry id="ldapRegistry" realm="Standalone LDAP Registry" ldapType="IBM Tivoli Directory Server"
    host="server" port="123"
    baseDN="baseDN" bindDN="bindDN" bindPassword="password"
    recursiveSearch="true"
    sslEnabled="true" sslRef="DefaultSSLConfig">
    <idsFilters>
        ...
    </idsFilters>
</ldapRegistry>
```

As you can see verifyHostname has the value 'false', but the check is done anyway.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDK has handles LDAP separately and hostname verification is enabled by default by the JDK. To disable LDAP hostname verification you need to set the system property com.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification to true.  So in the jvm.options in your server directory add -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true to disable hostname verification on an LDAP connention.